# save a DisplayObjects to be reused between scenes

Tags: coronasdk, corona-storyboard

How can I save a DisplayObjects to be reused between scenes?

Example:

scene1 contains the DisplayObject drawing.

In `scene:exitScene`  I save it to `storyboard.state.scene1.drawing`

Then when I get back to my scene in `scene:enterScene` I do:

```
drawing = storyboard.state.scene1.drawing
self.view:insert(drawing)
```

But I get an error as if drawing was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you store the reference to the displayobject in a variable, I would do it like this

No tested but the idea should work.

```
FromScene:

local displayObj=yourDisplayObject

-- when it is time to change scene, do it like this:

local options={
      local params ={
      dispObj = displayObj,
    },
}
storyboard.gotoscene(targetScene, options)


---
targetScene:

scene:createScene(event)
    local params=event.params
    local displayObj=params.dispObj
    --and then do whatever you want with displayObj
...
...
end
```

Doing it in this ways requires you to not nullify, or remove, the display object in destroyscene of the first scene.

Comment: No, I don't think you understand. I want to preserve the state of an object after the scene is destroyed. I don't want to pass it around asa a parameter to another scene.

Comment: How do you 1. Initialise the display object in the first scene and 2. When do you go back to this scene. If the display object is initialised using the local keyword it will be deallocated when the scene is destroyed. More code is appreciated!

Comment: Well the scene is recreated everytime it is activated. So:
- first time scene1 is created I create the object "drawing" as a new group. The user adds lines to this drawing.
- then the user switches the scene and scene1 is destroyed
- then the user goes back to scene1 and I want the same drawing to be there. 

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reuse the object in different Scene you can do this by creating an object lua file for example i will create a rect and save it as RectObject.lua

```
local H = display.contentHeight
local W = display.contentWidth
local myRect

myObject = {}

--the ScreenGroup parameter is the group from the scene where this object calls
function myObject:drawRect(ScreenGroup)
myRect = display.newRect(W/2 + 50, H/2, 50,50)
myRect:setFillColor(255,255,128)
ScreenGroup:insert(myRect)

end
```

so when i go to my scene i will just call it whenever i need it like this

```
require("RectObject.lua")

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    --calling Object from RectObject.lua
    myObject:drawRect(group) 

end
```

Note: that you need to pass the group to the object in order for it to remove to the scene when you exit.